# What does List<String> [] mean in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

i came across this syntax

```
List<String>[] result= new List[4];
```

I know what a list is in java and also generic but whats the purpose of the array bracket in this case. Does this mean it's an array of list of strings?

Comment: You have asked an answer :D

Comment: An Array of List of Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List[] result : Contains three things
1. List
2. []
3. result

1. Data type is List of strings
2. Array
3. variable name

So in this case result will store Array of List of string.

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String>[] = ...
```

Represents a variable declared to contain Datatype of List of Strings which is also an Array.

Although this sort of syntax is seldomly used.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example...

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> res[] = checkLists();
            System.out.println("Size of list1 : "+res[0].size());
            System.out.println("Size of list2 : "+res[1].size());
        }
    
        private static List<String>[] checkLists() {
   
            List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1","2");
            List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1","26","33");
    
            List<String>[] ress = new List[2];
            ress[0] = list1;
            ress[1] = list2;
            return ress;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).